# How to send the SMS more than 160 character?

Tags: android, sms

How to send big SMS in android. I used :

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(contactNos[j], null,msgs[i], sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

this code work only for 160 character message. i also use

```
ArrayList<String> msgsplit=sms.divideMessage(msgs[i]);
ArrayList<PendingIntent> listOfIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>(); 

for (int k=0; k < msgsplit.size(); k++){  
    Intent sentIntent = new Intent(); 
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MultipleMsg.this, 0, sentIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);  
    listOfIntents.add(pi);  
}
// sendMessage(contactNos[j],msgs[i]);
sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(contactNos[j],null,msgsplit, listOfIntents, null);
```

But it sends junk character in the message. 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-sms-mms-in-android

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Junk characters? method sendMultipartTextMessage only send **text** message. If you want to send non text message, you should look to method sendDataMessage. Below is the code excerpt from android [cts](http://gitorious.org/0xdroid/cts/blobs/ec65c6a1d77d2a3111c4cd624612caf680e6064b/tests/tests/telephony/src/android/telephony/cts/SmsManagerTest.java). It has example on how to send long messages.

```
SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
ArrayList<String> parts =sm.divideMessage(LONG_TEXT);
int numParts = parts.size();

ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveryIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

for (int i = 0; i < numParts; i++) {
sentIntents.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0, mSendIntent, 0));
deliveryIntents.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0, mDeliveryIntent, 0));
}

sm.sendMultiPartTextMessage(mDestAddr,null, parts, sentIntents, deliveryIntents)
```

Comment: I already try this and also put it in my question. No doubt this code split message and send it but at other side message comes with some unsupported characters in message.

Comment: seem like similar to the issue you encounter but they claim on simulator only. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13737

Comment: yap i also have same problem but i can't understand what's he said for send long message with out junk character.

Comment: this work on real device. Device not send junk character & work fine without any problem.

Answer (score 51):

Try below code might help

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(message);
sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, null, null);
```

Comment: i use this but it send junk characters in the message.

Comment: this code is working excellent for me. ( android 2.3.6, Samsung galaxy Ace), thanks very very much for sharing.

Comment: This works for me as well thanks, Nexus S running 4.2 Jelly Bean to an old Alcatel phone.

Comment: Working on latest OS - Nexus 5 Cheers!

Comment: @ingsaurabh: I tried this code, it works. However, on the phone from which I'm sending a message, it leaves one unsent message, and the same message sent?

Answer (score 3):

The emulator send the junk characters in that code during certain problem so use apk in real mobile , and check the code , I am sure that your application will not send junk message..All the best.

Answer (score 0):

You should get specific Short Code from SMSC, for  sending SMS which having characters more than 160.